# Martingale random sequence

Tags: probability-theory

Assume that $X_1, X_2, X_3,...$ are independent random variables such that for each $n$ it holds $X_n\geq0$ and $EX_n=1$. Define $$Y_n=\prod_{k=1}^{n}X_k$$
(1) Show that $Y=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Y_n$ exist almost surely with $E|Y|<\infty$.

(2) Show that $0\leq E[Y]\leq1$.

This is taken from problem 5.17 of Advance Probability book by Alexander Sokol.

I have proven that $Y_n$ is martingale. However, I don't have a way to solve these questions. I guess using the logarithm, but I don't know how to apply to this problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Take logs and use the strong law of large numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A non-negative super martingale converges almost surely (c.f. Theorem 4.2.12 Durrett PTE). Moreover, $0
\leq E Y \leq E Y_1 = 1$.